# .NET Web service called from android,gives java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed:ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I make one C# web service to get data from SQL database And I call that webservice in to my android app but i got error

> "java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection
>   reset by peer)"

Please give any suggestion. I try out all solution which given before on stack overflow

My code is below:

```java
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                    OPERATION_NAME);

// HeaderProperty hp=new HeaderProperty("Connection",
// "keep-alive");
// hp.setValue("close");
PropertyInfo propertyInfo1;
propertyInfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
propertyInfo1.setType(String.class);
propertyInfo1.setName("paycode");
propertyInfo1.setValue(paycode);
request.addProperty(propertyInfo1);

envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
envelope.dotNet = false;
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
envelope.bodyOut = request;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS).getServiceConnection().setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
httpTransport.debug = true;

Log.e("ENVELOPE_BODY", "" + envelope.bodyOut.toString());

// System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
Log.e("===============>", "Background...." + paycode);

httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); // Error Comes Here
httpTransport.getServiceConnection().setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

Comment: You need to look at your Android/Java stack trace (to get clues exactly *what* the client was doing when the server "pulled the plug"), and look at your server logs (possibly enabling trace-level logging), to determine *why* the server "pulled the plug". Of course, it's entirely possible somebody just kicked the network cable loose.  But I suspect that by looking at the client traceback and server logs, you'll be able to troubleshoot the root cause.

Comment: I Check my Web service from web browser its worked perfectly.

Comment: Can you give some information about the web service? Is it a WCF service, Web API, or legacy ASMX service?

Comment: Its an ASP C# , asmx web service

Comment: @Priti - all well and good that it "works from a web browser".  But it's *failing* on your Android.  To figure out *why*, your first steps are 1) reproduce the probem, 2) look at the client traceback, 3) look at the server traceback (and/or logs).

Comment: Thanks Paulsm, I have check server traceback, and i came to know its restrict my call so, I change my server settings then I check, it's run successfullyyy......

Comment: Beautiful - thank you.  SUGGESTION: Please add a "response" to your question.  (Re)state the symptom, copy/paste the lines in the server traceback that helped you identify the problem, and copy/paste the server settings you needed to change.  Then "accept" the response.